# SSH Connection to two ips and two roots in one In a single connection command

Tags: ssh, ip

In my current machine I login like:

ssh root@199.199.199.199

Then Inside of root@199.199.199.199 I do this:

ssh root:10.0.0.3 (freebsd jail environment ip alias interface)

This work, I want to know if is possible login directly like:

```
ssh root@199.199.199.199 goto root@10.0.0.3
```

From my current machine.

Thanks.

Note: both ips public and private interface have default port 22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following command:

`ssh -t root@199.199.199.199 "ssh -t root@10.0.03"`

The `-t` option will allocate a TTY to the second login.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [-J](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh) option?

If I understood your question correctly, and assuming you are using [OpenSSH](https://www.openssh.com/) client, you should be able to do

```
ssh root@10.0.0.3 -J root@199.199.199.199
```

If you can only reach your server at 10.0.0.3 by connecting to 199.199.199.199 first, you may even set the proper `ProxyJump` option for that host on your `~/.ssh/config` file and connect without specifiying the jump host.

Hope it helps!